# Database initialisation java, SQLite

Tags: java, database, sqlite

```
package com.example.financecontrol;

import java.sql.*;

public class DBController {
    public static Connection Connector() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:FinanceControl.sqlite");
            return conn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to initialise database with some data if it does not exist. The problem is that I want to add some tables and configs while launching the application for the first time?

Comment: You might want to learn about [database migration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration) tools such as Flyway and Liquibase.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What I needed is "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" statement. It worked properly!